# Error occured while opening Eclipse(See log file)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

I am new to Java. Currently I am facing problem with eclipse. I am unable to open Eclipse. I have tried to solve it by downloading the latest Eclipse but it does not help me. Here I am providing the log file. I can't understand where the problem located.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93365c156bd43fd6830a1aa63a5148e5

Comment: there is no log file. and mostly it solves by googleing the error code

Comment: please upload the log file to gist.github.com and post the link here. I can't see the log file in your question.

Comment: You have tagged this Java 7 - recent versions of Eclipse require at least Java 8 to run.

Comment: Check you are installed java appears in path.

Comment: Sorry . Here is the link. I have pasted the error file in this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93365c156bd43fd6830a1aa63a5148e5

Comment: What is your OS (windows, ubuntu ?) and the version of Eclipse (send us the link) you download  ?

Comment: currently i am using windows 10 and i have downloaded the latest version of eclipse.Here is the file name  eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64